# Get Auth token calling Aws Cognito Apis using client ID and secret token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to Aws. We have got a project where we have to write an sdk which accepts clentid and secret token in the auth header and talk to aws cognito to get the auth token. Can someone please guide me to the right solution. The application is purely backend where the user will call the api using client ID and secret key given at the time of integration. Thanks in Advance

Ni am new to Aws with very minimal knowledge

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you are asking. Do you need help in sending the token along with your aws SDK requests? Do you need help getting the token in the first place? Are you hoping for someone to write an entire solution? it may help to update your post to ask a specific question.

Comment: Hi @chrisstamper Thanks for your post . We have to write an Api which accepts client ID and secret key which will be created In aws cognito as part of  user pool creation and shared to the end user. The new Api have to call the cognito apis and get the token . The same token the end user will use in the subsequent api requests

Comment: We will be given an IAm role to access the Cognito.